# Adding Integers In A Vector

Tags: c++, vector, integer

Ok, I have another challenge. I have a question that asks me to "Read a set of integers into a `vecto`r. Print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements . Change your program so that it prints out the sum of the first and last elements, followed by the sum of the second and second-to-last, and so on."

Currently I have managed to get it to add consecutive numbers, not exactly in pairs, but as close as I can get it.

The only operators I have learnt thus far for `vectors`, and what the question wants me to use are: `v.empty();` `v.size();` `v.push_back(t);` `v[n];` `v1 = v2;` `v1 = {a,b,c...};` `v1 == v2;` `v1 != v2;` `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`

Here is my code as it stands now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::string; using std::vector; using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

int main ()
{
    vector<unsigned> numbers {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    unsigned sum;

    decltype(numbers.size()) count;
    for (count = 0; count < numbers.size(); ++count){
        sum = (numbers[count]++) + (numbers[count]);
        cout << sum << " ";
    }
}
```

So I can get it to add 5+6; 6+7; 7+8 etc... but as for each pair and all the rest, not 100% sure where to start. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `sum = (numbers[count]++) + (numbers[count]);` is a really bad line. `sum = 2*numbers[count]+1; numbers[count]++;` is much more clear;

Comment: For added fun, when your class reaches iterators, revisit this question and try to use std::transform. For extra points, try boost::transform_iterator then (`for` loop is forbidden).

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yea, I can't wait to get to the iterator chapter! Once I've digested all the info here I will finally move on!! Awesome!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two loops that print (1) sum of adjacent pairs and (2) the sum of opposite elements.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    vector<unsigned> numbers {5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};
    auto N = numbers.size();

    std::cout << "first part\n";
    for (size_t i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
       std::cout << numbers[i-1] + numbers[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "second part\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (N - 1 - i); ++i) {       
      std::cout << numbers[i] + numbers[N - 1 - i] << "\n";   
    }
    // in case you have an odd number of elements
    if (N % 2 == 1) std::cout << numbers[N / 2] << "\n";

}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1Nnjhi%2412)

Comment: This looks great! Can I ask though, the size_t, where is that defined or what exactly does it do?

Comment: @user1942453 `std::size_t` is defined in `<cstddef>` and it is an unsigned integral type large enough to hold a number of elements fitting in an STL container (such as vector). This automatically makes your code 64-bit proof. I updated the answer to `#include <cstddef>`

Comment: There is one last thing I am not quite getting... Why is it [N - 1 - i] in part 2? That is really confusing me a lot!

Comment: @user1942453 in c/c++ array indexing starts at 0, so the 1st element is `numbers[0]`, the N-th element is `numbers[N-1]` and the i-th from the end is `numbers[N-1-i]`

Answer (score 1):

*To print the sum of each pair of adjacent elements.*

```
auto count = numbers.size();
for (auto i = 0; i < numbers.size()-1; i++)
{
    std::cout << (numbers[i] + numbers[i+1]) << "\t";
}
```

*prints out the sum of the first and last elements, followed by the sum of the second and second-to-last, and so on*

```
for (auto i = 0; i < count/2; ++i) 
{       
   std::cout << (numbers[i] + numbers[count - i -1]) << "\t";     
}
```

Note: if vector has odd number, the middle one won't be calculated in second print

See [sample](http://ideone.com/jSBJb8) output

Comment: Incrementing the count will skip every second element in the vector.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that using a `count++` and `count` in the same expression is a [UB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Isn't it ?

Comment: @borisbn it should be ok, I can update to clear code, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your current code won't work for different examples. You need to change `numbers[count]++` to `numbers[count+1]` for it to work, and change the loop's end condition to `size()-1`.

As for your other question, you should be able to do it if you only loop through half the vector and add the numbers of `v[i] + v[v.size() - i - 1]`

Edit: Added `-1` to `v[v.size() - i - 1]` as suggested by borisbn in the comments

Comment: I think not `v[i] + v[v.size() - i]` but `v[i] + v[v.size() - 1 - i]`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried this on VS and it worked

```
vector <int> num;
num.push_back(5);
num.push_back(6);
num.push_back(7);
num.push_back(8);
num.push_back(9);
num.push_back(10);
int count = 0;
for(;count < (num.size()-1);count++)
{
        int sum =0;
        sum = num[count] + num[count+1];
        cout<<sum<<endl;
}
 for(int c =0; c < (num.size()-1);c++)
  {
   int altrsum = num[c]+ num[(num.size()-1)-c];
   cout<<altrsum<<endl;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! Thanks everybody for the overwhelming response! It's great!! This helps a lot, and it seems strikingly simple... makes me wonder why I couldn't quite get it. I definitely learnt something today!